# Difference between SHA1 and SHA1HMAC?

Tags: cryptanalysis, sha-1

Can anyone let me know the difference between SHA1 and SHA1HMAC algo?

Comment: HMAC takes a key, plain SHA-1 does not.

Comment: @CodesInChaos you mean SHA1(Data) and SHA1(Data + Key)? Can you please explain?

Comment: SHA1 only has one parameter, the data. HMAC-SHA-1 has two parameters, key and data. Simply concatenating key and data and passing them to SHA-1 is not a good idea. `SHA1(Data + Key)` is much weaker than HMAC-SHA-1, since it relies on collision resistance. `SHA1(Key + Data)` is totally broken, due to length extensions.